# Response is not fully loaded

Tags: java, reactjs, maven, newrelic

We are using react js as front end and Java( maven) as backend.
we have included the new relic script in the index.html page which is not allowing the full response to load. Therefore the application is not loading.

Below is the screenshot where in the response is not fully loaded.

[image]

New Relic script :
[image]